# Íconos en semantic UI

Tags: css, html5, css3, font-awesome, semantic-ui

```
<i class="huge icons">
  <i class="Facebook icon"></i>
  <i class="google plus circle icon"></i>
  <i class="twitter icon"></i>
  <i class="disabled linkedin icon"></i>
  <i class="add icon"></i>
  <i class="add sign icon"></i>
  <i class="add sign box icon"></i>
</i>
```

Estoy empezando a usar Semantic UI coloco este fragmento en una parte de la página y no sale nada... 
En el head tengo correctamente definido lo siguiente

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/semantic.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/semantic.css" >
```

digo "correctamente" porque lo uso con otros controles y va todo perfecto... 
Alguien que pueda decirme qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal ?

Comment: ¿Has comprobado que la ruta es correcta? Me refiero, ¿que el CSS está en una carpeta css al mismo nivel que tu fichero html?

Comment: Todo lo demás funciona perfectamente. De hecho dónde deberían mostrarse los iconos aparece vacío

Comment: Si La ruta fuera incorrecta no vería nada de lo otro

Comment: Sí, era simplemente por asegurar. Muchas veces las librerías tienen subcarpetas y es muy fácil equivocarse. En principio no veo nada raro en tu código. ¿Podrías agregar un ejemplo reproducible?

Comment: Tienes los ficheros de fuentes en la ruta themes/default/assets/fonts/ relativa a tu fichero semantic.css?

Comment: Mmmmmmm "creo" que sí

Comment: ahi copié esa carpeta que vi que no la habia copiado !!!... Gracias José... puse eso y funcionó perfecto !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que yo veo es que estás aplicando mal la sintaxis para agrupar íconos, si todo lo que quieres es mostrarlos uno al lado del otro, debes aplicar la clase huge a cada ícono (por cierto "facebook" debe ir en minúscula).

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <i class="huge facebook icon"></i>
  <i class="huge google plus circle icon"></i>
  <i class="huge twitter icon"></i>
  <i class="disabled linkedin icon"></i>
  <i class="add icon"></i>
  <i class="add sign icon"></i>
  <i class="add sign box icon"></i>
</div>
```

La clase `huge icons` es para sobreponer íconos, tal y como lo muestra el ejemplo de la documentación:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i class="huge icons">
  <i class="big red dont icon"></i>
  <i class="black user icon"></i>
</i>
```

Comment: Ah ok ahora en un rato pruebo

Comment: Shaz, estuve viendo que agregando solamente el "huge" seguia sin mostrarme nada entonces vi que las diferencias entre el codigo que pusiste y el mío eran las referencias a los archivos css y js de semantic... vi que pusiste un link a los repositorios mientras yo los tengo en una carpeta css en el servidor... puede que me falte algun componente ? Yo descargue el zip de semantic y leí por ahi que solamente recuperando el css y el js alcanzaba. Vi que hay un directorio también y por ahi no estoy copiando toda la estructura del directorio...

Comment: COPIE LA CARPETA THEMES dentro de la carpeta css donde tengo el css de semantic y funcionó perfecto apuntando al css local de semantic !!! muchas gracias Shaz !!!